# Python Splitting PDF Leaves Meta-Text From Other Pages

Tags: python, pdf

The following code has successfully split a large PDF file into smaller PDFs of 2 pages each. However, if I look into one of the files, I see meta-text from others.

This is used to split the PDF into smaller ones:

```
import numpy as np
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
inputpdf = PdfFileReader(open(path+"multi.pdf", "rb"))
r=np.arange(inputpdf.numPages)
r2=[(r[i],r[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(r),2)]
for i in r2:
    output = PdfFileWriter()
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i[0]))
    output.addPage(inputpdf.getPage(i[1]))
    with open(path+"document-page %s.pdf" % i[0], "wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

This is used to get the meta-text of one of the resulting files (PyPDF2 will not read it):

```
import pdfx
path=path+'document-page 8.pdf'
pdf = pdfx.PDFx(path)
pdf.get_text()
```

My issues with this are:

1. The process is super slow and all I want is a 10 digit number in the upper-right corner of the first page. Can I somehow just get that part?
2. When looking at the result, it has text from other adjacent pages from the original PDF file (which is why I'm calling it "meta-text"). Why is that? Can this be resolved?

Update:

```
pdf.get_references_count()
```

...shows 20 (there should only be 2)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of python, and the libraries are you using? I'm getting an error using get_text(), but can get the metadata with get_metadata(). Split pdfs made by PyPDF2 seem to work normally for me.

Comment: Python 3.6, PyPDF2 1.26.0, pdfminer.six 20170720, pdfx 1.3.0, Numpy 1.13.1

Comment: Even when I split the PDFs in Adobe and save as smaller files, I have the same issue. Maybe it's just something about this PDF file.

Comment: *"Maybe it's just something about this PDF file"* - if you shared the file, we could analyse it...

Comment: I would, but it contains sensitive information.